# Best math lib for displaying formulas

Tags: php

I know [PHPMathPublisher](http://www.xm1math.net/phpmathpublisher/) but it's not OOP and uses lots of deprecated functions. But afteral it's perfect. Simple user interface and so on. But are there anything better for PHP 5.3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know or use LaTeX, then you could look into using [Mathjax](http://www.mathjax.org/).  It's a JavaScript library that you can use to render LaTeX in the browser.